# Does an AJAX PostBack reset the session timeout?

Tags: asp.net-ajax, session-timeout

I know that if I do a full post back to the server through a button click or other server control, that the internal session timeout is reset.

However, if I have a button that is wrapped within an UpdatePanel, or another piece of code wrapped within an AJAX post back to the server, will the internal session timeout be reset as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/654213-ajax-updatepanel-not-resetting-iis-session

> The updatepanel uses XMLHTTPRequest to
>   get the html to display in the panel.
>   XMLHTTPRequest will send the session
>   cookie, but on response it does not
>   read and update the browser's session
>   cookie, so after 20 mins the session
>   cookie times out (in the browser) and
>   is no longer sent to the server.   you
>   can switch to cookieless sessions or
>   update the browser cookie using a
>   server request via an img or iframe.

Comment: Perfect, just what I needed to know. Thanks!